# Copying data from struct net_device_stats to user space

Tags: c, struct, kernel, call, system

I would like to have a little help with this problem, I need to copy data from the struct net_device_stats of eth0 to userspace to show it to the user.I know I should be doing this with a system call and some people recommended me to make a function that receives a pointer to net_device_stats, and then use the function struct net_device_stats *(*get_stats)(struct net_device *dev). I don't have much idea of this so I would like to hear tips and recommendations from you about how to approach this problem and what should I have in mind

Sorry for my vague English and thank you, if I shouldn't be asking this here please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should use sysfs for that. For example, see /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics

There are many examples in Linux under drivers/net directory.

Comment: But I need to do it the way I explained :( it is for an assignment, thank you anyways